# JsonEditor integration with Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-widget, django-admin-tools, django-jsonfield

I am working on integrating [JSONEditor](https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor/) into the Django admin.  There is one field in my model that uses the Postgres JSON and the Tree editor in this library is perfect.

### models.py

```
class Executable(models.Model):
    """ Simplified model for sake of the question."""

    recipe = JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I've made decent progress (I think) integrating the JSONEditor library within the appropriate create/edit screen in the Django Admin. The data is *displayed* correctly upon loading but for some reason when I make edits within the JSONEditorWidget the changes are not saved.  I'm sure there is some `save` override that I need to work on, or that I'm missing something obvious, but I'm really not sure where to go from here.

### admin.py

```
import json
from django import forms, utils
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Executable


class JSONEditorWidget(forms.Widget):
    html_template = """
        <div id='%(name)s_editor_holder'></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                var options = {
                    "mode": "tree",
                    "search": true
                };
                var %(name)s_editor = new JSONEditor(container, options);
                var json = %(value)s
                %(name)s_editor.set(json);
                %(name)s_editor.expandAll();

                var json = %(name)s_editor.get(json);
        </script>
        <textarea readonly class="vLargeTextField" cols="40" id="id_%(name)s" name="%(name)s" rows="2" height="20px">%(value)s</textarea>
    """
    def __init__(self, attrs=None, formats=None, defaults=None):
        self.formats = formats
        self.defaults = defaults
        super(JSONEditorWidget, self).__init__(attrs)

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        if isinstance(value, basestring):  # Edit existing instance
            value = json.loads(value)
        result = self.html_template % {
            'name': name,
            'value': json.dumps(value)
        }
        return utils.safestring.mark_safe(result)


class ExecutableForm(forms.ModelForm):
    recipe = forms.CharField(widget=JSONEditorWidget())    # Kwargs here?

    class Meta:
        model = Executable
        fields = '__all__'

    class Media:
        css = {
            'all': ('http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/app.min.css',)  # TEMP
        }
        js = (
            'http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/app.min.js',   # TEMP
            )


class ExecutableAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Executable
    form = ExecutableForm
    fields = (('request', 'status'), 'recipe')


admin.site.register(Executable, ExecutableAdmin)
```

Comment: @e4c5 The library is well-documented and available on Github. What makes you think it is not? Btw, I'm still a novice programmer so maybe I've missed something :)

Comment: I am sorry I misunderstood, i had not used this library before but upon visit to the site there were no visible developer or github links

Comment: @e4c5 no worries, the link is buried in the footer and I could see how you could come to that conclusion. I've updated the link in my post to point to the GitHub repo and not the demo site ( https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor/ )

Answer (score 13):

My solution for Django 1.10.2, jsoneditor#^5.5.9, Postgres 9.5:

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class Consumer(models.Model):
    data = JSONField(default=dict, db_index=True)
```

**admin.py:**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

from .models import Consumer


class JSONEditorWidget(forms.Widget):

    template_name = 'jsoneditor.html'

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        context = {
            'data': value,
            'name': name
        }

        return mark_safe(render_to_string(self.template_name, context))


class ConsumerForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Consumer
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'data': JSONEditorWidget()
        }

    class Media:
        css = { 'all': ('jsoneditor/dist/jsoneditor.min.css',) }
        js = ('jsoneditor/dist/jsoneditor.min.js', )


class ConsumerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['pk']
    model = Consumer
    form = ConsumerForm

admin.site.register(Consumer, ConsumerAdmin)
```

**jsoneditor.html:**

```
<div id="{{ name }}_editor"></div>

<textarea cols="40" id="id_{{ name }}" name="{{ name }}" rows="10" required="" style="display: none">{{ data }}</textarea>


<script>
    console.log('jsoneditor.html');
    var container = document.getElementById("{{ name }}_editor");

    var options = {
        modes: ['code', 'tree'],
        search: true,

        onChange: function () {
            var json = editor.get();
            document.getElementById("id_{{ name }}").value=JSON.stringify(json);
        }
    };

    var editor = new JSONEditor(container, options);
    var json = {{ data|safe }};
    editor.set(json);
</script>
```

> Blockquote
>   Written with [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/).

Comment: I have been looking for something like this for a while now... thanks

Comment: Sorry but this didn't work perfectly for me. I had to add minor tweaks esp. converting json text to json `var json = JSON.parse({{ data|safe }});` and renaming `onChange` to `change`.  Following is the updated gist https://gist.github.com/rgupta2/761fd987254703673d83426912dc015d