# Django. How can I edit JSONField (PostgreSQL 9.6) in standard Django admin?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

My Django version is **1.11.8**, Python 3.6.1 and PostgreSQL 9.6. I create Django model with [JSONField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield). For example, like this:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
from django.db import models

class Dog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    data = JSONField()
```

And put some data:

```
>>> Dog.objects.create(name='Rufus', data={
...     'breed': 'labrador',
...     'owner': {
...         'name': 'Bob',
...         'other_pets': [{
...             'name': 'Fishy',
...         }],
...     },
... })
```

But how I can edit this JSON data in admin page? I mean, something like transform all `key: value` data to normal fields into Django Admin. For example:

```
'breed': 'labrador' ---transforms---> CharField(name='breed', ...) with value 'labrador'
```

Some use cases and useful comments are welcome.

Comment: you need to create widget for your self

Comment: @Gahan Can you give some example please?

Comment: read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37535618/jsoneditor-integration-with-django-admin or https://github.com/nnseva/django-jsoneditor